# Can Asterisk play rtsp streams?

Tags: audio, video, asterisk, rtsp, ivr

How can I configure asterisk to play an RTSP url? there is an official application app_rtsp which is buggy. I could not make it work. Is there any official way or any other alternative?

Answer (score 0):

You can try the Dialogic open source project [DiaStar](http://www.projectdiastar.org/)